# How to add new caller to contacts ? ( BQ Aquaris E4.5 )

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris

I got a call from an unknown number and now I want to add it to my contact list. How can I do that straight from the calls scope without trying to memorize the phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose the call, that you want to save the number of
2. Click on Call (this does not dial immediately)

[image]

3. Left of the number you see an icon depicting a person with a plus sign

[image]

4. Pressing it you get to the Add Contact option, where you can create a new contact or add the number to an existing one.

[image]